# netft sensor integration with UR5?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, rosmake, sensor, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to integrate the `netft sensor` mounted on **ur5** with ROS groovy (on Ubuntu 12.04). I also came across this particular stack  [here](http://wiki.ros.org/netft). As I understand, this stack is built using `rosmake` and it is still associated with the `old ROS versions(Diamondback, Fuerte)`. Has anyone tried to implement and integrate this stack in `groovy`, more specifically using `catkin_make`? If yes, requesting you to kindly share the details.

This tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/netft_rdt_driver/Tutorials/RunningNetFTNode), seems to be very latest. This is what I would like to achieve in `groovy`. I would also want to understand the effort/steps involved in making the changes?

Awaiting your response,

Thanks and Regards,

Murali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109396/netft-sensor-integration-with-ur5?/) by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 246 on 2013-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe late but for people looking for it, I have catkinized the `netft` metapackage.

Repository: github.com/fsuarez6/netft

---

Originally posted by [Francisco](https://answers.ros.org/users/17926/francisco/) with karma: 31 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) on 2014-05-14**:
well ... It is kind of late :) ... But anyway thank you for updating. Just another query? would it be possible to use the above mentioned with ros-groovy? if yes can you please share the steps involved? Thanks again.

**Comment by [Francisco](https://answers.ros.org/users/17926/francisco/) on 2014-05-14**:
Yes, it should work. Just follow the instructions in the repository.